# How to make ID column visible in the list view

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following Groovy Domain class and generated scaffold controller for it.

When I create a Book row in the table, the ID column is invisible on the list view.

Is there anyway to make ID column visible on the view? I tried visible:true but it seems not making any difference.

```
class Book {

    String bookAuthor

    static constraints = {
        bookAuthor blank: false, maxSize:30
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
        id generator: 'sequence',
        params: [sequence:'s_book_seq']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the generated scaffolding views and add an id field manually. If you need to do this for a large number of domain classes, modify the scaffolding templates instead; you can install the templates using `grails install-templates`, they will be copied into `src/templates`

Comment: Yes. That worked. Thanks. It would be nicer to have it controllable by property such as visible:true or false. But acceptable I guess.

Comment: If you were to have a "visible" property in your domain class, you would be dictating view decisions from your model, which goes completely against the entire MVC paradigm.

Comment: True in a way, but the fact that the database ID is important to some business process and not just an implementation detail does matter to the domain model and if the view reacts to this by displaying it in the scaffolding templates, I don't see any harm in it. Grails already allows you to influence scaffolding through domain classes via the [widget](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/widget.html) constraint.